# Where can I find documentation for Ember 0.9.8?

Tags: ember.js

I have a client from years ago that wants a few changes to an Ember app that was written in `ember-0.9.8`. I haven't used ember since then, and I know a lot has changed. But, I still need to refer to the old documentation, and the website seems to only go back as far as 1.10.

Comment: The documentation is in the code and the git repo should go back to that time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ember v0.9.8 was release on May 21, 2012.   This is a little before any of their git repos for the guides.

The guides back then were within the emberjs repo and had to be built manually.

Download the release: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/releases/tag/v0.9.8
The README.md file has instructions for building the documentation.

> ## Building API Docs
>
> The Ember.js API Docs provide a detailed collection of methods,
>   classes, and viewable source code.
>
> NOTE: Requires node.js to generate.
>
> See http://emberjs.com/ for annotated introductory documentation.
>
> ### Preview API documenation
>
> - run `rake docs:preview`
> - The `docs:preview` task will build the documentation and make it available at http://localhost:9292/index.html
>
> ### Build API documentation
>
> - run `rake docs:build`
> - HTML documentation is built in the `docs` directory

You can give it a try, but good luck - it might be tough.

Comment: Thanks, at first I didn't see `v0.9.8` in the tags list on github, but after cloning the repo the tag does in fact exist.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Lux the API documentation is in the code and that one is on GitHub. You could find the ember code at that point of time by tag. The [readme](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/v0.9.8.1#building-api-docs) contains information about how to generate the API docs. If you are lucky it will still work.

[v0.9.8.1](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/af957ea2c58d434c14ea00d0381b20be39178a9f) was released on 23 May 2012. That's quite a long time for a web application to run without any major refactoring. Ember has changed hardly since then.